# Most Parsimonious Elastic Net Model - choosing $\alpha$ and $\lambda$

Tags: feature-selection, regularization, caret, glmnet, elastic-net

How do I calculate which Elastic Net model is the most regularized/parsimonious?

I am recreating GLMnet in another language as an exercise. I want to do a grid search over several values of alpha and lambda, and then take the most parsimonious model with a prediction error within 1 standard error of the mean of the smallest prediction error. (I think this is similar to what the R package caret does.)

My question is, how do I choose 'most parsimonious'? A higher lambda means stronger regularization, as does a higher alpha, but how do I combine the two?

Comment: Optimize through cross validation, and all else equal, pick the model with the fewest non-zero features. That means less data to store and process.

Comment: @Emre But what if I have two models with the same number of features but different coefficients?

Comment: The same number of nonzero features AND cross validation metrics??

Comment: Know that parimony is the enemy of predictive discrimination and stability.  And what do you mean by prediction error?  If it is not a proper accuracy scoring rule then model/feature selection on the basis of that measure will entail a ton of randomness.  Also I'd like to see clear justification for the 1 SE rule.

Comment: A higher alpha does not mean stronger regularization; alpha governs the balance between $L_1$ versus $L_2$ penalty rather than intensity of the penalty.

Comment: "alpha controls the “mix” of ridge and lasso regularisation, with alpha=0 being “pure” ridge and  alpha=1 being “pure” lasso"... https://eight2late.wordpress.com/2017/07/11/a-gentle-introduction-to-logistic-regression-and-lasso-regularisation-using-r/

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the error surface is convex; the optimum is the point with the best out-of-sample performance metric. There is a contour line that corresponds to 1 s.e. around the maximum. Selecting any $(\alpha, \lambda)$ pair on that contour line which is within 1 s.e. of the optimum, but you have to decide upon a way to select among alternative $(\alpha, \lambda)$ pairs. One method would be to select the point on the contour which lies in the direction of larger $\lambda$ with the justification that no point on the contour has stronger regularization. This must be the most parsimonious model within 1 s.e. of the minimum because it applies the largest penalty to the coefficients.